# Executable wont' run after moving to a different folder

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, g++, g++4.8

I had an existing c++ program that I compiled in Ubuntu 14.04 using `g++-4.8`. To run this program on the terminal by passing it a file, which prints processed data in the console:

```
#./my_program.cpp.exe < data.in

EMPLOYEE ID IS            1
MARITAL STATUS IS         s
YOUR GROSSPAY IS          100
YOUR TAX AMOUNT IS        5
YOUR NETPAY IS            95
```

This program is stored in `~/Documents/module2`. I created a 
new directory `~/Documents/module3` and copied both files, `my_program.cpp.exe` and `data.in`, to this folder and now when I run it, it doesn't print any output to the console.

```
#./my_program.cpp.exe < data.in
#
```

I'm not sure if this is a c++ issue or a Linux/Ubuntu issue so I'm asking here. I feel like it could be either or them.

When I list the files they show:

```
#ls
-rw-r--r-- 1 user    user
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user    user    my_program

... plus other files (11 total)
```

but when I list the folders they come up as:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 user    user    module3
drwxrwxr-x  3 user    user    module2
```

which I'm not sure if that 2 after the permissions makes sense.

to get info from the file I'm using:

```
ifstream fin( "employee.txt" ); // Declare file streams
```

no so no hardcoded links other than the same dir where running the program. All I do afterwards is basic math and print to standard output:

```
cout << " EMPLOYEE ID IS            " << employeeid << endl;
```

I "diff-ed" both files (data.in and my_program.cpp.exe) with the originals and they are identical.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Without seeing any relevant code it's impossible to answer this question. Please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you try to debug?

Comment: Note: The 2 and the 3 after permissions are the number of sub-directories, including `.` and `..`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I added more info about how it reads from the file and how it prints to stdo.

Comment: @Naveen I'm not sure I understand what you mean or where to start. I'm new to C++. The program compiled and ran with no errors. When copied to another folder I get no output but no errors. All I'm using is vim and g++.

Comment: So your program open a file for input from the programs working directory. What do you think happens if the file is not there? Did you forget to copy that file?

Comment: @JonnyHenly Thanks, now it makes sense. I miss read previously and thought it was supposed to be the total number of files.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Both files exist in both directories. I expect the same result. I "cat-ed" the data.in file to make sure it had something in it and the data is there. I "diff-ed" both files (data.in and my_program.cpp.exe) with the originals and they are identical.

Comment: Please update your question to include an *actual* [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and also a full directory list of both directories, with file sizes (i.e. `ls -l`).

Comment: `ifstream fin( "employee.txt" );`– are you absolutely sure that you're reading from standard input and not from a file called "employee.txt" that you didn't copy?

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks for your answer and reading through my post. Seems like that might be related to the issue. While creating that "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example" when I changed the name I got the expected output. Now here's the weird thing, I tried to pass it "data.in" but first created an empty file  named "employee.txt" by executing `touch employee.txt` and it worked. By worked I mean it read the data from "data.in" as long as there's a file named "employee.txt".

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm new to C++ so I'm just starting to get familiar with ifstream. Right now I'm passing the data by redirecting the file when I run the program from the terminal. I'm not sure why but it seems like it would read data from a redirected file other than the specified as long as the file exists in the same directory. I'm not sure how to interpret this.